# Fixing a program using 4 swap functions in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, swap, memory-address

Beginner programmer here. I have an assignment due tomorrow that demonstrates a poorly written program, and we have to "fix" it for a grade. There is no description about what the program is supposed to do. I'm assuming they want us to swap numbers using 4 different methods.

All of the methods work up until swap4, where it shows me an address of memory instead of a value.

I'm almost certain it's the line:

```
int *p1 = &num1;
int *p2 = &num2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
p2 = &num2;
```

That is making it not work.

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap1(int& n1, int& n2)
{
    int temp = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = temp;
}

void swap2(int& n1, int& n2)
{
    int temp = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = temp;
}

void swap3(int* p1, int* p2)
{
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

void swap4(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 2;

    cout << "Before invoking the swap1 function, num1 is: " 
    << num1 << " and num2 is: " << num2 << endl;

    swap1(num1, num2);

    cout << "After invoking the swap1 function, num1 is " << num1 <<
    " and num 2 is: " << num2 << endl;

    cout << "\nBefore invoking the swap2 function, num1 is: "
    << num1 << " and num2 is: " << num2 << endl;

    swap2(num1, num2);

    cout << "After invoking the swap2 function, num1 is: " << num1 << 
    " and num2 is: " << num2 << endl;

    cout << "\nBefore invoking the swap3 function, num1 is: " << num1 <<
    " and num2 is " << num2 << endl;

    swap3(&num1, &num2);

    cout << "After invoking the swap3 function, num1 is: " << num1 <<
    " and num2 is: " << num2 << endl;

    int *p1 = &num1;
    int *p2 = &num2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    p2 = &num2;

    cout << "\nBefore invoking the swap4 function, p1 is " << p1 << " and p2 is"
    << p2 << endl;

    swap4(p1, p2);

    cout << "After invoking the swap4 function, p1 is " << p1 << "and p2 is"
    << p2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it me, or is `swap1` the same as `swap2` and `swap3` the same as `swap 4`?

Comment: `p2 = &num2;` won't be a problem, since `p2` is already equal to `&num2`. The line doesn't do anything.

Comment: `swap3` and `swap4` swap the values the the pointers point to, they don't swap the pointers themselves.

Comment: You're printing `p1` and `p2`, which are pointers, so you are getting address, which is normal. If you want the associated value, you should print `num1` and `num2` since these are the values pointed to by `p1` and `p2`, or print `*p1` and `*p2` instead.

Comment: After you digest all that, `std::swap(num1, num2);`

Answer (score 4):

The entire exercise is really unclear because the code is "poorly written" in many aspects:

- Using almost the same function name for functions that are (maybe) supposed to do very different things (swap pointers vs swap pointer contents). Or, if they are supposed to all do the same thing, ...
- ...using identical functions on identical inputs for no deeper reason. Note in particular the amount of code duplication that should probably be abstracted away.
- `using namespace std;` is a pretty bad idea.
- Writing custom swap functions instead of using `std::swap` as appropriate.

It's pretty obvious that the point is to demonstrate the difference between references and pointers, but the instruction "it's bad, fix it" is too broad to allow a definitive solution.

More to the point, there is no specification whether `swap4` should swap pointers or their contents. If the former is correct then the function is wrong, if it's the latter then the printout is at least misleading.

Comment: Just a (very) minor one, but still: mixing C style `\n` and C++ style `std::endl`...

Comment: @Aconcagua There's nothing wrong with using `'\n'` with `std::cout`. `std::endl` does extra stuff like flushing the stream which you may not necessarily need every time you need to end a line. It's not a question of style, `'\n'` and `std::endl` do slightly different things.